# What's a formal synonym for "in one go"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine you're writing a literature book in English and you want to mention something like the following,

> I wanted to crush all the pepper *in one go*, so I used a bigger tool and crushed all of them at once.

I feel like it's not very formal in academia, so what would be a formal word for *in one go*?

(I don't care if my sentence is not grammatically correct, so don't worry about it, I just need a formal synonym.)

Comment: I wanted to crush the pepper quickly... etc, instead of a word that works, make the sentence work for you.

Answer (score 4):

I commented earlier to this effect, but was asked to put that into an answer. So ...

I would say that ***all at once*** fits the bill here rather nicely.

You almost came to it yourself when you said "crushed all of them at once"—but using that together with "in one go" is superfluous at that point. One or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 2):

You could say '[at one fell swoop](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/at-one-fell-swoop.html)'.

Bit of a cliché, though, and you should avoid clichés like the plague.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest (from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/attempt))

> **attempt**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> An effort to achieve or complete a difficult task or action.

The question mentions 'formal' and 'academia' so I presume it's not entirely about cookery, though I could offer

> Jan flipped the pancake at the first attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You’ve already found your synonym (*all at once*), and the *OED* has your back. It even uses *in one go* to define it:

> **all**, *adj.*, *pron.*, and *n.*, *adv.*, and *conj.*
>  PHRASES
> **P18.**
> **a.** all at once.
> **(a)** With everything happening in one go or simultaneously; at one and the same time; all together.
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Here are some selected usage examples given:

> <sub>1588   W. KEMPE *Educ. Children* sig. F2v   A sillable
> of eight letters, being too hard for a childe to learne all at once,
> he may learne letter by letter.</sub>
>
> <sub>1662   R. MATHEWS *Unlearned Alchymist* (new ed.) §82. 109
>   She..popt it into her mouth, and swallowed it all at
> once.</sub>
>
> <sub>1706   *Phillips’s New World of Words* (new ed.) at *Orgues*
>   Several Musket-Barrels set in a row within one wooden Stock, to
> be discharged either all at once, or separately.</sub>
>
> <sub>1930   *Lancet* 27 Sept. 686/2   The recently prepared
> solution is warmed to body heat and may be quite safely injected all
> at once provided it is injected slowly.</sub>
>
> <sub>1995   *Daily Mirror* 23 Feb. 6/4   Transfer of other
> powers to the new Assembly likely to be phased in rather than
> introduced all at once.</sub>

So:

> *I wanted to crush the pepper all at once, so I used a bigger tool.*

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to crush all the pepper **in one batch**, so I used a bigger tool
> and crushed all of it at once.

**batch** (n.)

> The quantity of material prepared or required for one operation
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/batch)

I've changed *them* to *it*, since you refer to *pepper*. If you are talking about black pepper, you could also say:

> I wanted to crush all the pepper corns **in one batch**, so I used a bigger tool
> and crushed all of them at once.

Comment: In cooking, one usually does not encounter black pepper in batches.

Comment: True, but we're not talking about the quantity purchased or called for in a recipe--the OP has a few containers'/measures' worth that they want to process in a single batch.

Comment: Containers' worth? For pepper? Black pepper is not processed, it is crushed/ground up, in cooking. Why not admit defeat?

Comment: When I buy black pepper corns, they are in a glass spice container/small jar and I use it to fill a pepper mill. Evidently the OP is crushing their own pepper--what do you want from me??

Comment: Actually, pepper corns are ground up (aka "crushing") and they cannot be ground up "at one go" so the question and answers make zero sense.

Comment: This may work for the OP's specific example of crushing pepper, but I don't think that *in one batch* is generally interchangeable with *in one go*. Something could have been processed in one batch, but if there were interruptions and pauses between different steps of the processing, or if several attempts at doing it needed to be made, we wouldn't say that it was done in one go.

Comment: I think the subject and nature of the processing is important--alternatives for "in one go" may vary depending on what we're talking about and what "one go" consists of.

Answer (score 0):

"with one whack" comes to mind.

- "I wanted to crush all the pepper **with one whack**, so I used a bigger tool."

> - a smart or resounding blow [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whack)
> - a sharp, swift blow [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/whack)

...tried to split the log with one whack.

...and killed the snake with one whack.

Comment: That sounds even more informal to me!

Comment: I don't think one whacks pepper. It would go all over the place. You can whack a steak to flatten it, or pork, but not pepper.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **at a [single] stroke** etc:

> *at one stroke {also, at one blow; at a stroke or blow; in one stroke or blow}*
>
> At the same time, with one forceful or quick action.

[[The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+one+stroke)]

Although usually used metaphorically nowadays, literal examples do exist:

- *Somerset is said to have gone straight up to the unsuspecting Wenlock and at a stroke felled him with his poleaxe.*

[[A Companion and Guide to the Wars of the Roses
By Peter Bramley](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FjQ9AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT220&lpg=PT220&dq=%22at+a+stroke%22+felled&source=bl&ots=DWZhqhoHoQ&sig=ACfU3U3HEmvaZAgTPpp3QoRF9M_w0EqtyA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmzIzkxNL1AhWPTcAKHaNWBBwQ6AF6BAgnEAM#v=onepage&q=%22at%20a%20stroke%22%20felled&f=false)]